# How to get function to narrow return value type to specific subtype instead of returning union or index type

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns an object with the same shape except for one property, which may be named `value` or `defaultValue`, whichever the value is of `valueProp`. Here is a simplified example:

```ts
type ValueType = 'value' | 'defaultValue'
function props0(valueProp: ValueType) {
  return {
    [valueProp]: 'value',
    other: 'other',
  }
}
```

It seems like it should be able to infer that that the return type is *either* `{value, other}` or `{defaultValue, other}`, but when I pass it to a function that expects one or the other, like this:

```
function expectsDefaultValue({defaultValue, other}) {
  console.log('defaultValue:', defaultValue)
}

expectsDefaultValue(props0('defaultValue'))
```

, it complains that the value I'm trying to pass is of type `{ [x: string]: string; other: string; }` instead of the expected/desired type, `{defaultValue, other}`:

```
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; other: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ defaultValue: any; other: any; }'.
  Property 'defaultValue' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string; other: string; }' but required in type '{ defaultValue: any; other: any; }'.ts(2345)
```

### Use index type?

I guess that makes sense, in that anytime you try to use a dynamic property like that, it sees it as an [index type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types). Is there any way to get this to work with narrowing of the index type to the expected type?

It seems like I should at least be able to do a [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) that *tells* TypeScript that it is in fact in the correct shape, but no...

```
expectsDefaultValue(props0('defaultValue') as PropsUsingDefaultValue)
// => Conversion of type '{ [x: string]: string; other: string; }' to type
// 'PropsUsingDefaultValue' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently
// overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to
// 'unknown' first.
// Property 'defaultValue' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string; other:
// string; }' but required in type 'PropsUsingDefaultValue'.
```

That index type keeps giving that same old problem. The only way to "force it" appears to be this, which seems unacceptable, which is why I am here searching for a better solution:

```
expectsDefaultValue(props0('defaultValue') as unknown as PropsUsingDefaultValue)
```

### Not use index type?

If index types have too many limitations (the key can only be of type `string`, when really I'd like to define the key to be of type `ValueType`)...

**How do I make this function generic *without* index types, and without any extra duplication?**

My next attempt was to use an `if/else` branch to explicitly return an object in the right shape, but this is just too verbose and has too much duplication to be considered acceptable:

```js
interface Props {
  other: any
}
interface PropsUsingValue extends Props {
  value: any
  other: any
}
interface PropsUsingDefaultValue extends Props {
  defaultValue: any
  other: any
}

function props1(valueProp: ValueType): PropsUsingValue | PropsUsingDefaultValue {
  if (valueProp === 'value') {
    return {
      value: 'value',
      other: 'other',
    } as PropsUsingValue
  } else {
    return {
      defaultValue: 'value',
      other: 'other',
    } as PropsUsingDefaultValue
  }
}
```

And even then I can't just do this:

```
expectsDefaultValue(props1('defaultValue'))
// => Property 'defaultValue' is missing in type 'PropsUsingValue' but 
// required in type 'PropsUsingDefaultValue'.ts(2345)
```

(Why doesn't it infer the correct, specific return value type here?)

but can do this:

```
expectsDefaultValue(props1('defaultValue') as PropsUsingDefaultValue)
```

I guess returning a union type (`PropsUsingValue | PropsUsingDefaultValue`) confuses TypeScript here (or I'm missing something else)...?

### Conditional types?

Maybe there's some way to use a [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) to make it clear that we only return one or the other of those types rather than the union of those type?

I tried this but don't know how to debug or resolve the error it's giving:

```
function props2<VT extends ValueType>(valueProp: VT):
  VT extends 'value' ? PropsUsingValue : PropsUsingDefaultValue
{
  if (valueProp === 'value') {
    return {
      value: 'value',
      other: 'other',
    } as PropsUsingValue
    // => Type 'PropsUsingValue' is not assignable to type 'VT extends "value" ? PropsUsingValue : PropsUsingDefaultValue'.ts(2322)
  } else {
    return {
      defaultValue: 'value',
      other: 'other',
    } as PropsUsingDefaultValue
  }
}
```

### Mapped types?

Since index types seem to have limitations (key can only be of type `string` or `number`), maybe we give mapped types a try? (But how exactly?)

### Limitation of generics?

Seems like I'm doing something similar to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995#issuecomment-463445339, but apparently there's a limitation of generics where generics extending unions (which `ValueType` is) cannot be narrowed.

How do we work around this limitation (or rewrite so we don't run into it)?

### Use helper function to infer the actual type

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836259/typescript-index-signatures/50836336#50836336) maybe?

### A mapping table between types?

This looks promising:

[Narrowing a return type from a generic, discriminated union in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312206/narrowing-a-return-type-from-a-generic-discriminated-union-in-typescript)

Maybe I will try that next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution should be pretty simple. You can use a generic signature for the function to capture the actual type of the parameter. We can then use `Record` to create the desired type:

```
type ValueType = 'value' | 'defaultValue'
function props0<T extends ValueType>(valueProp: T): Record<T, string> & { other : string}
function props0(valueProp: ValueType) {
  return {
    [valueProp]: 'value',
    other: 'other',
  }
}

let { defaultValue, other } = props0('defaultValue') //ok
let { value } = props0('value') // ok
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigcgG6Io5QA+uAJhAGZxILDzIQ4BQVSAdgMbACWA9hyhgATvzABnAAwAeVFAgAPYBA7kJsQmgwA+ABQEmABTFgAXFFQBKCwCUIXfiPJyANFAnARvDgHMdUABkUADeUPzAABYQIlAWnt5+AL5snDwCQqLi0gZaJuIWjCjokFahLFBQIhDASCJCIRWVUADahij5YAC6FvhaOK5NlRHRIr0jMQNNKSksCDWhUJQ0dAxa7hOxSVDYWZJSejjLtPRFzGUA9Bf8ANZzC2Ht0Nu7pjl9TDiXF+E3QA)

---

#### Variant that avoid using function overloads

```
type ValueType = 'value' | 'defaultValue'

type Props<T extends ValueType> =
  Record<T, string> 
  & { other: string }

function props<T extends ValueType>(valueProp: T): Props<T> {
  return {
    [valueProp]: 'value',
    other: 'other',
  } as Props<T>
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigcgG6Io5QA+uAJhAGZxILDzIQ4BQLokUACgE4D2YAM4AeVFAgAPYBAB25QbEJoMAPiiYWUKACUIAYz49yogDRRBwHgEsZAczWaoAMigBvKH2AALCDwBc5pY2tlAAvmxUSDJ6wFZ8MlBg-EKi4lKy8opM6JAqABQETLwCAagAlAHFKahqro48EMBIPAl1WloA2oUoVQC6AfhKOCaOWp4+-rjjvsOOoVBwClUiNSzhLAD0G1CoEBaCLAiNblCUNHQMSmbTPGHqicmCeThntPSMRGVQWx4A1ofHdzdaDzbBJARPQZMHBfH58f4sSLRWLxNKQGKCAAi1DelyYeVcrwuHwg128vlClUewheOOJQxUXzaUAMMkEfCOADoEHxbM8ie8lH5hqc6YKmGU1ixJOjgFixXiUHlwUJ+QqSTDYdt4dKJLL5edxUqVZDgZrvttfPweGZFmj9NJyEA)

Comment: Thanks. I knew there must be a way to do this with generics to avoid needing explicit if/else branches! I think this is what I was looking for. At least it seems like the best solution so far. (I still need to apply this to my original problem and see if I run into any limitations.) I also love that this avoids the need for explicitly defining a bunch of extra types (like `IValueResult`, `IDefaultValueResult`).

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid using function overloads if possible, and they didn't seem like they should be necessary, so I played around with your solution until I came up with this: [link in next comment, because [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts#comment737312_313622)]. I'll edit your answer to add this variant..

Comment: Variant that avoid using function overloads: [Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigcgG6Io5QA+uAJhAGZxILDzIQ4BQLokUACgE4D2YAM4AeVFAgAPYBAB25QbEJoMAPiiYWUKACUIAYz49yogDRRBwHgEsZAczWaoAMigBvKH2AALCDwBc5pY2tlAAvmxUSDJ6wFZ8MlBg-EKi4lKy8opM6JAqABQETLwCAagAlAHFKahqro48EMBIPAl1WloA2oUoVQC6AfhKOCaOWp4+-rjjvsOOoVBwClUiNSzhLAD0G1CoEBaCLAiNblCUNHQMSmbTPGHqicmCeThntPSMRGVQWx4A1ofHdzdaDzbBJARPQZMHBfH58f4sSLRWLxNKQGKCAAi1DelyYeVcrwuHwg128vlClUewheOOJQxUXzaUAMMkEfCOADoEHxbM8ie8lH5hqc6YKmGU1ixJOjgFixXiUHlwUJ+QqSTDYdt4dKJLL5edxUqVZDgZrvttfPweGZFmj9NJyEA)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using function overloading

```
type ValueType = 'value' | 'defaultValue'

interface ICommonResult {
  other: string;
}

interface IValueResult extends ICommonResult {
    value: string;
}

interface IDefaultValueResult extends ICommonResult {
    defaultValue: string;
}

type Result = IValueResult | IDefaultValueResult

function props0(valueProp: 'value'): IValueResult
function props0(valueProp: 'defaultValue'): IDefaultValueResult
function props0(valueProp: ValueType): Result  {
    const obj = { other: 'other' };

    if (valueProp === 'value') {
      return { value: 'value', ...obj }
    }

    return { defaultValue: 'value', ...obj }

}

function expectsDefaultValue({defaultValue, other}: IDefaultValueResult) {
  console.log('defaultValue:', defaultValue)
}

expectsDefaultValue(props0('value')) // Fails
expectsDefaultValue(props0('defaultValue')) // OK
```

[Link To Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigcgG6Io5QA+uAJhAGZxILDzIQ4BQLAlgHbAQBONAY2gBJAMIB7ALaTxnAEoQAznWBQA3iyhRxwABZ8AXFEXBeXAOYBuFgF82XHvzhCowxigXL6UCAA8enOSKrhLSsp4q6ppaUARMRiZmnFa29tx8giIAItS09O4QEd5+AUEhUjLySpEaMVCUNCoFCaYW1nYsoJBQRarYboSF1d5kwjmN+YO9bFRInALA7LJQYLziYIoADAAUcSgACmtgRviDOACURgNM07Pzi8ur61u7g4frJw15DGeXruPfAq3OYLJacFZHF57CDvY6wQboSB-XpaWoxASyEzaABGACsoNg1No9IZcDp9LxiDZrNEtOwqFBXkxYQTMNhTkwLlE6lpeBBgEheOCidCTtCcAAaKAAOll4jxUDsdQ6dT5AqF6nquSagzFZylsul8vxHQ6d1Byz8kAWigBOqY2zUX3tKCl5L4NiudsmN2GwHO3KgGM4inECAg0oQ4nM2xwzp9KAMkq1Ex+THOqRYVogNu9aZQ2yeGx2HKI5wDAHoK1AAGJwdgIRRZ3zW4C27UJiCFyEl+P55jlqBVqAAeQA0kA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's close to some of the things I've tried. I would really prefer to avoid explicitly enumerating the options with if/else branches (and the duplication it requires) though, and also avoid function overloads (for the same reasons), if at all possible... So I am going to prefer answers that use valueProp directly as a key...